# jQuery ajax post success not getting correct data on localhost using XAMPP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm doing an ajax post with jQuery to a php file and am trying to get the success function data to come in correctly. Here are my files:

JAVASCRIPT

```
$.ajax({ url: "ajax/chart-kpi-trend.php",
         data: {
            data_kpi: kpi,
            data_goal: goal,
            data_year: year,
            data_month: month
        },
         type: 'POST',
         success: function(data) {
                      alert(data);
                  },
         error: function() {
            alert('error');
         }
         });
```

PHP

```
$goal = $_POST["data_goal"];
$kpi = $_POST["data_kpi"];
$year = $_POST["data_year"];
$month = $_POST["data_month"];


$return = array(
    goal => $goal,
    kpi => $kpi,
    year => $year,
    month => $month
    );

echo json_encode($return);
```

Now the success function is called, however the data passed into it is this...

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="author" content="Kai Oswald Seidler">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<title>XAMPP for Mac OS X 1.7.3</title>

<frameset rows="74,*" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" border="0" borderwidth="0">
    <frame name="head" src="head.php" scrolling=no>
<frameset cols="150,*" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" border="0" borderwidth="0">
    <frame name="navi" src="navi.php" scrolling=no>
    <frame name="content" src="start.php" marginwidth=20>
</frameset>
</frameset>
</head>
<body bgcolor=#ffffff>
</body>
</html>
```

Which is completely different from the array I've constructed in the PHP file. I'm developing on localhost with XAMPP, could that be a problem, or is it somewhere in my code?

Cheers!

Comment: What is the expected data? Try setting the `dataType: "html"` in your `$.ajax` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your PHP file is located at www.yourdomain.com/ajax/chart-kpi-trend.php then you need to add another leading / to the URL in your Jquery ajax request, so your javascript would be:

```
$.ajax({ url: "/ajax/chart-kpi-trend.php",
     data: {
        data_kpi: kpi,
        data_goal: goal,
        data_year: year,
        data_month: month
    },
     type: 'POST',
     success: function(data) {
                  alert(data);
              },
     error: function() {
        alert('error');
     }
     });
```

Without the leading / the Javascript is looking for www.yourdomain.com/whereverYourJavascriptIs/ajax/chart-kpi-trend.php. Looks like your XAMPP is just catching the fact that there is no page found at the URL that it is being given and showing a generic XAMPP page. That is why you are getting back that information (the page's html) instead of the information that you expected to receive.

Comment: That was it! It was redirecting to the XAMPP overview page since the url didn't exist (for some reason). I had to give the absolute url in order for it to work. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({ url: "ajax/chart-kpi-trend.php",
     data: {
        data_kpi: kpi,
        data_goal: goal,
        data_year: year,
        data_month: month
    },
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'JSON',
     success: function(data) {
                  alert(data);
              },
     error: function() {
        alert('error');
     }
     });
```

if you called the correct URL, just add the "dataType: json" parameter in ajax object to ge the json response

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$return = array(
    'goal' => $goal,
    'kpi' => $kpi,
    'year' => $year,
    'month'=> $month
);

echo json_encode($return);
```